# Parsing HTML5 <video> element with html-react-parser

Tags: typescript, dom, next.js

I have some HTML content that is being returned from a CMS that I wish to display in a NextJS V13 app. I am using the `html-react-parser` package rather than `dangerouslySetHtml` to parse the HTML content as I also wish to replace some embedded tags such as `<a>`, `<img>` and `<video>` with corresponding React components `<Link>`, Cloudinary's `<CldImage>` and a custom React `<VideoPlayer>` component respectively.

The `<a>` and `<img>` element replacements are working fine, however I cannot figure out how to extract the `<video>`'s "src" attribute from the `domNode` to pass it along to the `<VideoPlayer>` component.

For example, my code is similar to the following:

```
import parse, { Element, HTMLReactParserOptions } from "html-react-parser"
import VideoPlayer from "@/components/video-player"

export default function ArticleContent({ content }: { content: string }) {
  const parserOptions: HTMLReactParserOptions = {
    replace: (domNode) => {
      // Replace embedded <video> tags with <VideoPlayer>
      if (domNode instanceof Element && domNode.name === "video") {
         return <VideoPlayer src={domNode.<???? WHAT GOES HERE ???>} />
      }
    }
  } 

  return (
    <div>
      {parse(content, parserOptions)}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Finding the path to the `<video>` "src" attribute within `domNode` has been challenging. Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. My replacement condition should look like:

```
if (domNode instanceof Element && domNode.name === "video") {
  // TODO: Figure out correct type assertions so typesript doesn't complain
  // @ts-ignore
  return <VideoPlayer src={domNode.children[0].next.attribs.src}  />
}
```

Typescript is complaining about some type mismatches, but it works. I just need to figure out what the correct type assertions are required so that typescript is happy (for now, the @ts-ignore solves that issue).